# rails2 to rails3 upgrade problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I am trying to upgrade my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.0.3.

Models:
Project.rb

```
has_many :project_roles, :dependent => :destroy  
alias :roles :project_roles  
after_create :create_cal_for_project, :make_project_owner

def create_calendar_for_project
  self.calendars.create(:name => "default")
end

def make_project_owner
  #Make owner of project when created
  self.roles.create(:user => User.curr_user, :name => 'O')
end
```

ProjectRole.rb

```
belongs_to :project  
belongs_to :user
```

project_roles table columns are user_id, project_id, name
I am getting a hard time with the following error, please suggest.

Thanks.

```
→ rails c
> Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)  

ruby-1.9.2-p0> User.curr_user = User.first  

=> #<User id: 1, username: "tispratik", login_email: "tispratik@gmail.com", > is_email_verified: nil, crypted_password: "deed6fa27ffefa57e63592a9b59295abf2660447cf281f34857...", password_salt: "YsD2nLte3pZy1FZ78GD", persistence_token: "84e44908be77b2dc1e41f8dfeacf9ef20c30050ff0c53854e0d...", single_access_token: "cp1bqVSheDh7vl9J48V", perishable_token: "6pGPzdw48nJnJAHsIZQW", last_login_ip: nil, last_login_at: nil, created_at: "2010-11-23 06:00:09", updated_at: "2010-11-23 06:00:09">  

ruby-1.9.2-p0> p = Project.create(:name => "ad", :description => "add")  
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:57:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:56:in `map'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:56:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_InsertStatement'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `block in accept'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:110:in `with_connection'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:17:in `accept'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/tree_manager.rb:19:in `to_sql'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-2.0.4/lib/arel/select_manager.rb:191:in `insert'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:14:in `insert'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:270:in `create'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:47:in `create'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `block in create'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_create_callbacks'  
... 30 levels...
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in save'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block in save'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:248:in `rollback_active_record_state!'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `save'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `create'  
 from (irb):2  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'  
 from /home/pratik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'  
 from script/rails:6:in `require'  
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The problem is in the make_project_owner callback. create_calendar_for_project runs just fine.

I changed make_project_owner to the following still the same problem occurs.

```
def make_project_owner
  #Make owner of project when created
  #role.create(:user => User.curr_user, :name => 'O')
  ProjectRole.create(:user => User.curr_user, :project => self, :name => "O")
end
```

I tried downgrading rails:
rails 3.0.2 -> has same problem
rails 3.0.1 -> has different error

```
undefined method `name' for #<Arel::Value:0x00000005795090>  
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace  

arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `block in create'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `each'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `detect'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `create'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/algebra/relations/writes.rb:24:in `call'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/session.rb:17:in `create'  
arel (1.0.1) lib/arel/algebra/relations/relation.rb:159:in `insert'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/relation.rb:14:in `insert'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:271:in `create'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:47:in `create'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `block in create'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_create_callbacks'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `create'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:247:in `create_or_update'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create_or_update'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run_save_callbacks'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in     with_transaction_returning_status'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block in save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:248:in `rollback_active_record_state!'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `create'  
app/models/project.rb:70:in `make_project_owner'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:463:in `_run_create_callbacks'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `create'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:247:in `create_or_update'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create_or_update'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `_run_save_callbacks'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `create_or_update'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:39:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:237:in `block in save'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:248:in `rollback_active_record_state!'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:236:in `save'  
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:34:in `create'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:460:in `_run__2176748434120211400__process_action__1031157339911956458__callbacks'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:133:in `dispatch'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:173:in `block in action'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'  
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'  
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'  
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'  
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'  
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'  
haml (3.0.24) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:287:in `call'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'  
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'  
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'  
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'  
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'  
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'  
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'  
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'  
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'  
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'  
/home/pratik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'  
/home/pratik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'  
/home/pratik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please try to format this better.

Comment: I can't read this garbled error-message, but it is probably obvious that one of your `:after_create` callbacks is causing the error. Try disabling both of them, then each one in turn, that should get you closer to find a cause (i assume the mismatched callback-names is just an editing error).

Comment: Updated the format to look a little better. Still dosent look as pretty :( Also, i found that the problem is in make_project_owner callback and also tried the above change, still the same error.

Comment: One thing to note is that both the Project and ProjectRole models have the :name field, not sure if there is a name clash.

Comment: Looks like this is an existing issue with Arel. I would appreciate if someone looks into it. Thanks!  

Lighthouse ticket https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5322-rails3-rc-arel-does-not-work-with-multiple-schemas-using-mysql#ticket-5322-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but i was able to solve this with the following code:

```
module Connection
class DB1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    establish_connection(Rails.env)
end

class DB2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    establish_connection("#{Rails.env}_db2")
end
end

class Project < Connection::DB1
```

Maybe it worked for me because of the usages of establish_connection in all models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this so I cannot say for sure, but this line looks suspect to me:

```
self.calendars.create(:name => "default")
```

I would think it should be like this:

```
Calendar.create(:name => "default", :project_id => self.id)
```

Comment: The problem is in make_project_owner callback.

Comment: I would guess it is because you are calling ProjectRole.create. Try calling Role.create.

Comment: Since Role is just an alias of ProjectRole, its not letting me use it. Am getting the following error.  
    uninitialized constant Project::Role

Comment: I could finally run it using a hardcoded sql.  
    def make_project_owner  
      #Make owner of project when created  
      #self.roles.build(:user => User.curr_user, :name => 'O')  
      connection.execute("Insert into project_roles(project_id, user_id, name) values(#{self.id}, #{User.curr_user.id}, 'O')")
    end